# Numbers in math mode when using the iwona package

Tags: fonts

I am using the iwona font package with the options math, light and condensed. Now what happens is that in the math mode the package does not use the numbers it has (which are used in the text) but uses the CM version of the numbers. I want the numbers in the math mode be the same as the numbers in the text (and hence with the rest of the document). Is there a package option that fixes this? If not what is the work around?

Comment: In view of Will Robertson's answer, please provide a minimal example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Additionally, it would help to know what TeX engine you're using: pdfTeX, LuaTeX, XeTeX, ….

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this; I get the Iwona numbers in both text and math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math,light,condensed]{iwona}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
0123456789
\[0123456789\]
\end{document}
```

I'm using TeX Live 2010 with the following file list:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   iwona.sty    2005/10/03 v.1.2 Iwona package (MW)
ot1iwonalc.fd    2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OT1/iwonalc (MW)
ot1iwonalcm.fd    2005/10/05 v1.2 font definition file for OT1/iwonalcm (MW)
omliwonalc.fd    2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OML/iwonalc (MW)
omsiwonalc.fd    2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OMS/iwonalc (MW)
omxiwonalc.fd    2008/07/22 v0.995 font definition file for OMX/iwonalc (MW)
```

Comment: I get the same exact output but before that I have the following line:"LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/iwonalcm/m/n' undefined
(Font)" and "using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6." I think this should be it but I don't know why the font shape is missing ...

Comment: What distribution are you using?